# ghci 'Not in scope:' message

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm going through the 'Learn you a Haskell' tutorial and I am at this part:

```
lucky :: (Integral a) => a -> String
```

When I try to execute this line I get:

```
<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: `lucky'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-line commands in GHCi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443035/multi-line-commands-in-ghci)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is not a function code, it's function signature which can only be saved in a module along with function definition and the be loaded to GHCi.

This signature means that you're going to define a function `lucky` which gets an `Integer` and returns a `String`.

However if you're composing your functions using GHCi as interactive interpreter, you can let Haskell infer your function's type, e. g.:

```
ghci> let lucky x = show (x + 1)
ghci> :t lucky
lucky :: (Num a) => a -> String
```

Comment: Is there any way to add another definition to ghci with pattern matching. Something like `let lucky 4 = "four"`

Answer (score 17):

If you want to try in the GHCI you could use multi-line command block

```
:{
lucky :: Int -> String
lucky a = show(a)
:}

:type lucky 
lucky :: Int -> String
```