# Non-exhaustive patterns exception

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Still learning Haskell with Get Programming with Haskell.

In the lesson 7 there is the following exercise:

> The `tail` function in Haskell returns an error when called on an empty list. Modify `myTail` so that it does handle the case of an empty list by returning the empty list.

Where `myTail` is defined as follows:

```hs
myTail (_:xs) = xs
```

In the very same lesson, we are told that it is possible to check empty lists parameters with pattern matching. Here is an example from the book:

```hs
isEmpty [] = True
isEmpty _ = False
```

So here it is what I thought would do the trick

```hs
myTail [] = []
myTail (_:xs) = xs
```

However, when I use this function with an empty list it throws an exception:

```hs
ghci> myTail []
*** Exception: <interactive>:2:1-17: Non-exhaustive patterns in function myTail
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce it, are you sure you're running the latest version of the code?

Comment: `ghci --version` returns `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.2.4.`.

Comment: I mean, the latest version of your code (i.e. have you re-compiled after the change), not the compiler.

Comment: Oh wait, are you running in ghci? IIRC, you can't just define functions with pattern matching in ghci, the next `let myTail` will just create the entire new function (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733266/pattern-matching-in-ghci))

Comment: You can use `:{` and `:}` in ghci to enter a function/expression on multiple lines.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846050/how-to-define-a-function-in-ghci-across-multiple-lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems you are defining your function entirely within ghci, the most likely source of your problem is that each line is introducing a *new* `myTail` function. In this case when you call `myTail []` the current `myTail` function does not handle empty lists, so you get an exception.

```
ghci> myTail [] = []
ghci> myTail (_:xs) = xs
ghci> myTail []
*** Exception: <interactive>:3:1-18: Non-exhaustive patterns in function myTail
```

You can define a function across multiple lines using `:{` and `:}`.

```
ghci> :{
ghci| myTail [] = []
ghci| myTail (_:xs) = xs
ghci| :}
ghci> myTail []
[]
```

It is worth additionally noting, though, that it doesn't make much sense for a function that returns the tail of a list to return an empty list when given an empty list when in fact an empty list doesn't have a tail.

You may want to use `Maybe` to handle this possibility.

```
ghci> :{
ghci| myTail [] = Nothing
ghci| myTail (_:xs) = Just xs
ghci| :}
ghci> :t myTail
myTail :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
ghci> myTail []
Nothing
ghci> myTail [1, 2, 3]
Just [2,3]
```