# Any way to add patterns, type signature, to a function in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghci

*^-- No, it doesn't entirely.  My question covers ADDING patterns and type signatures interactively...which is apparently impossible.*

The most basic things you might try do from early tutorials won't work in GHCi:

```
foo [] = []
foo (x:xs) = x : foo xs
```

That works if you put it into `foo.hs` and at the GHCi prompt type `:load foo.hs`.  You can then invoke foo on a list and get the list back.

Early Google searches tell you that in GHCi you need a `let` statement.  But in this case (a function defined with multiple patterns) it won't work:

```
Prelude> let foo [] = []
Prelude> let foo (x:xs) = x : foo xs
Prelude> foo [1, 2, 3]
[1,2,3*** Exception: <interactive>:3:5-27: Non-exhaustive patterns 
    in function foo
```

The second "let" overwrote the first "let".  Leaving out the let isn't an option.  And it doesn't like it if you type in expressions like `foo :: [a] -> [a]` either.

The tutorials seem to sidestep this and send you quickly into putting your code into files.  What if you don't want to make a file, and want to work interactively?  What are the options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define a function in ghci across multiple lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846050/how-to-define-a-function-in-ghci-across-multiple-lines)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-line commands in GHCi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443035/multi-line-commands-in-ghci)

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan I've read that.  That isn't the same question.   And the knowledge that a "let" statement would group with everything after it is a very specific oddity.  So basically if I have a file full of definitions from a tutorial, I say "let" once and it doesn't matter what the ensuing contents are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You cannot add new patterns or a type signature to a function in GHCi after you have run a statement defining it in the evaluator.

For that matter, you shouldn't see it as "adding" on a line-by-line basis in source code, either.  It's merely a notation convenience.  So when you look at a "multi-line" definition like:

```
foo :: [a] -> [a]
foo [] = []
foo (x:xs) = x : foo xs
```

Those foo definitions must all be tied together as a group.  You can't split them up...so for instance, this will cause an error:

```
foo :: [a] -> [a]
foo [] = []

bar = 3

foo (x:xs) = x : foo xs
```

*(Note: The type signature may be separated, however.  For the details of how far it can be separated, see [How is 'block' granularity in Haskell defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978563/how-is-block-granularity-in-haskell-defined) )*

To put things together as a group, you can use multi-line input in GHCi.  Or you could do it all on one line with semicolons:

```
let foo :: [a] -> [a] ; foo [] = [] ; foo (x:xs) = x : xs
```

But you can't type in an input, test it, then patch individual patterns in and out, and test it again.  The whole function is redefined with each `let`.

Answer (score 2):

Use multiline input:

```
Prelude> :set +m
Prelude> let
Prelude| foo [] = []
Prelude| foo (x:xs) = x : foo xs
Prelude| 
Prelude> foo [1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: Is there no way to specify N patterns, try it, get a problem, and adjust it without a multi-line input specifying all the patterns again?

Comment: @HostileFork, not at the moment.  There is a suggestion that an entire multiline input can be restored from the input history but it is not yet implemented.

Comment: Hmm.  It seems one cannot split up the patterns for foo with an interspersed other definition *(such as `foo [] = []` followed by `bar = 3` then `foo (x:xs) = x : foo xs`)*  So even if you're entering them in source, they are effectively defined all in an instant... so there is no "line-by-line" even there.  Correct?

Comment: @HostileFork All the equations for one function/variable must be consecutive, same as in a file. And everything from the `let` to the empty line is parsed in one go, as a `let` block. (GHCi is being lenient by not requiring extra indentation for the block items in this case.)

Comment: @HostileFork BTW in GHCi (and lambdabot) I tend to use explicit `;` and the very occasional `{}` braces (not as often needed as you'd think) instead of multiline. Mostly old habit, but this does have the advantage that I *can* usually re-edit the whole line in one go.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks...see [my attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24978075/211160) at answering my own question.  Any nuance you care to add?  It seems the type signature may be separated from the function definitions, but you can't independently do a let of a type signature that I can tell...

Comment: @HostileFork Indeed, the type signature isn't required to be consecutive with the equations, but it must be in the same block.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Is there a formal definition of a Haskell "block" pertinent to this?  I see "do-block" mentioned, but if you are using source files then what is the granularity of a block?

Comment: @HostileFork Curiously the Haskell Report barely uses the term "block", speaking of [layout](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7) instead. There are four standard kinds, `where`, `let`, `do` and (`case`) `of` blocks. The first two are the ones which can have function declarations and the like. A whole source file is technically an optional module declaration followed by a kind of `where` block.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Interesting enough point for a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978563/how-is-block-granularity-in-haskell-defined), I think...