# haskell: factors of a natural number

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function in Haskell that calculates all factors of a given number except itself.

The result should look something like this:

```
factorlist 15 => [1,3,5]
```

I'm new to Haskell and the whole recursion subject, which I'm pretty sure I'm suppoused to apply in this example but I don't know where or how.

My idea was to compare the given number with the first element of a list from 1 to n `div`2
with the `mod` function but somehow recursively and if the result is `0` then I add the number on a new list. (I hope this make sense)

I would appreciate any help on this matter

Here is my code until now: (it doesn't work.. but somehow to illustrate my idea)

```
 factorList :: Int -> [Int]
 factorList n  |n `mod` head [1..n`div`2] == 0 = x:[]
```

Comment: try using a list comprehension: http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension

Comment: If looking for very efficient version see: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factors_of_an_integer#Haskell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to handle this. But first of all, lets write a small little helper:

```
isFactorOf :: Integral a => a -> a -> Bool
isFactorOf x n = n `mod` x == 0
```

That way we can write `` 12 `isFactorOf` 24 `` and get either `True` or `False`.  For the recursive part, lets assume that we use a function with two arguments: one being the number we want to factorize, the second the factor, which we're currently testing. We're only testing factors lesser or equal to `` n `div` 2 ``, and this leads to:

```
createList n f | f <= n `div` 2 = if f `isFactorOf` n
                                     then f : next
                                     else next
               | otherwise      = []
    where next = createList n (f + 1)
```

So *if* the second parameter is a factor of `n`, we add it onto the list and proceed, otherwise we just proceed. We do this only as long as `` f <= n `div` 2 ``. Now in order to create `factorList`, we can simply use `createList` with a sufficient second parameter:

```
factorList n = createList n 1
```

The recursion is hidden in `createList`. As such, `createList` is a [worker](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Worker_wrapper), and you could hide it in a `where` inside of `factorList`.

Note that one could easily define `factorList` with filter or list comprehensions:

```
factorList'  n = filter (`isFactorOf` n) [1 .. n `div` 2]
factorList'' n = [ x | x <- [1 .. n`div` 2], x `isFactorOf` n]
```

But in this case you wouldn't have written the recursion yourself.

#### Further exercises:

- Try to implement the `filter` function yourself.
- Create another function, which returns only *prime* factors. You can either use your previous result and write a prime filter, or write a recursive function which generates them directly (latter is faster).

Comment: As a personal preference, I like to have the complete code in one place, followed by explanations. That way I can copy-paste and run it, which is often the best way to discover how it works. Having the code split out in paragraphs makes that difficult.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I disagree. Those are three different implementations of `factorList`. They are not meant to be copy-pasteable, as you, the reader, have to choose between the equivalent implementations. If the code was meant to be copied plainly, then I'd have used literate Haskell (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32476604/1139697 for an example of a literate answer). And the essential part of the answer is: create simpler building blocks, e.g. `isFactorOf`.

Answer (score 0):

@Zeta's answer is interesting.  But if you're new to Haskell like I am, you may want a "simple" answer to start with.  *(Just to get the basic recursion pattern...and to understand the indenting, and things like that.)*

I'm not going to divide anything by 2 and I will include the number itself.  So `factorlist 15 => [1,3,5,15]` in my example:

```
factorList :: Int -> [Int]

factorList value = factorsGreaterOrEqual 1
  where
    factorsGreaterOrEqual test
      | (test == value) = [value]
      | (value `mod` test == 0) = test : restOfFactors
      | otherwise = restOfFactors
      where restOfFactors = factorsGreaterOrEqual (test + 1)
```

The first line is the type signature, which you already knew about.  The type signature [doesn't have to live right next to the list of pattern definitions for a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978563/how-is-block-granularity-in-haskell-defined), (though the patterns themselves need to be all together on sequential lines).

Then `factorList` is defined in terms of a helper function.  This helper function is defined in a `where` clause...that means it is local and *has access to the value parameter*.  Were we to define factorsGreaterOrEqual globally, then it would need two parameters as value would not be in scope, e.g.

```
factorsGreaterOrEqual 4 15 => [5,15]
```

You might argue that factorsGreaterOrEqual is a useful function in its own right.  Maybe it is, maybe it isn't.  But in this case we're going to say it isn't of general use besides to help us define `factorList`...so using the where clause and picking up value implicitly is cleaner.

The indentation rules of Haskell are (to my tastes) weird, but [here they are summarized](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation).  I'm indenting with two spaces here because it grows too far right if you use 4.

Having a list of boolean tests with that pipe character in front are called "guards" in Haskell.  I simply establish the terminal condition as being when the test hits the value; so `factorsGreaterOrEqual N = [N]` if we were doing a call to `factorList N`.  Then we decide whether to concatenate the test number into the list by whether dividing the value by it has no remainder.  *(`otherwise` is a Haskell keyword, kind of like `default` in C-like switch statements for the fall-through case)*

Showing another level of nesting and another implicit parameter demonstration, I added a where clause to locally define a function called `restOfFactors`.  There is no need to pass test as a parameter to restOfFactors because it lives "in the scope" of `factorsGreaterOrEqual`...and as that lives in the scope of `factorList` then value is available as well.

Comment: If something grows too far to the right when you indent with 4 spaces, you probably should rewrite it to nest less.