# Cartesian product over a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, combinatorics, cartesian-product

Given a list of lists of length `x` where all the sublists have the same length `y`, output the `y^x` lists of length `x` that contain one item from each sublist.

Example (`x = 3`, `y = 2`):

```
[ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] ]
```

Output (`2^3 == 8` different outputs):

```
[ [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 6],
  [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 4, 6] ]
```

## My research / Work

**Ruby**

I wrote actual code to perform this task, but in Ruby, as it is the language I am most comfortable with.

```
def all_combinations(lst)
   lst.inject {|acc, new| acc.product(new).map(&:flatten) }
end
```

**Type**

Input is a list of lists that contains items of type a and so is the output.

```
allProduct :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

**Cartesian product, flattening and folding**

Looking at my Ruby solution makes me think that a good use of these functions may be enough to solve the problem. The problem is that while the Cartesian Product outputs a list of tuples but I need a list of lists.

Comment: `allProduct = sequence`.

Comment: @Zeta but Hoogle says the type is `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]` while I need `[[a]] -> [[a]]`

Comment: `m` is the list type constructor (`[]`), in this case. You can always make the type of `allProduct` more specific, if you want: `allProduct = sequence :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`.

Comment: @Jubobs wow it works... how should I search hoogle in the future in order to catch monadic types?

Comment: What did you try? Searching [`[[a]] -> [[a]]`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B%5Ba%5D%5D+-%3E+%5B%5Ba%5D%5D) returns a hit for `sequence`.

Comment: @Jubobs  I saw that the type was not exactly the same so I wrongly thought it was of no use to me. I will learn to check also similar types when searching hoogle, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @Jubobs I have another doubt: you say _You can always make the type of allProduct more specific_ but how can `[[a]]` be more specific than anything if `a` already indicates any type?

Comment: `[[a]]` is more specific than `m [a]` and `[m a]`, because `m` (in the type signature of `sequence`) stands for *any* monad, but `[]` is just *one* instance of `Monad`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89147/discussion-between-caridorc-and-jubobs).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<sub>Note: This post is written in literate Haskell. Save it as
*.lhs and load it in GHCi.</sub>

```
> -- remove this line if you don't have QuickCheck installed
> import Test.QuickCheck
```

---

## A simple recursive variant

Lets start with a simple variant of `allProduct`:

```
> allProductFirst :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
> allProductFirst []     = [[]]
> allProductFirst (x:xs) =
```

Now `x` itself is a list again. Let's say that `allProduct xs` would give us the product of the other lists.

```
>    let rest = allProductFirst xs
```

What do we need to do? We need to create a new list for every element in `x` and concat them together:

```
>    in concatMap (\k -> map (k:) rest) x
```

Note that this variant isn't 100% correct, as `allProduct []` is `[[]]`.

## A monadic variant

How would this look like if we were to use the `Monad` instance of `[]`?

### Using `do` notation

```
> allProduct' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
> allProduct' []     = [[]]
> allProduct' (x:xs) = do
```

We want to take every element of `x`

```
>      elementOfX <- x
```

and cons it onto all the possible suffixes our list can have:

```
>      rest       <- allProduct' xs
>      return $ elementOfX : rest
```

This means we're basically evaluation every action inside our list monad. But there's a function for that: `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`. If we use `m ~ []`, its type can be specialized to `sequence :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`.

### Using `sequence`

We end up with our last variant:

```
> allProduct :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
> allProduct = sequence
```

## Testing the result

We use QuickCheck to test that it's likely the same as `allProductFirst`
and `allProduct'`:

```
> main :: IO ()
> main = do
>   quickCheck $
>     forAll (choose (1,8)) $ \n -> -- number of lists
>     forAll (choose (1,4)) $ \s -> -- number of elements per list
>     forAll (vectorOf n $ vector s) $ \xs ->
>       allProduct'     xs === allProduct (xs :: [[Integer]]) .&.
>       allProductFirst xs === allProduct xs
```

Use `:main` in GHCi, `runhaskell` or compile and run your program, and you
should end up with 100 passed tests.

Comment: *We use QuickCheck to prove that [...]* "Proove" is too strong a term. How about "increase our confidence"?

Comment: @Jubobs Changed it to "test that it's likely the same" is more honest, I think. But I concur, that wasn't a "proof".

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: QuickCheck is like pseudo-proving compared to Agda's or Idris' proper proofs.

Comment: `sequence` is wrong because `sequence []` is empty.

Comment: @PyRulez `allProduct []` isn't defined by OP, so it's ambiguous. That being said, the Ruby code ends up with the `nil` on the empty list, so there is no valid base case for a Haskell translation. The ambiguous behaviour is also mentioned in the answer, although not in detail: *"Note that this variant isn't 100% correct, as `allProduct []` is `[[]]`"*. Ask OP what `allProduct []` should be. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯