# Cartesian product of arbitrarily many lists of different types

Tags: haskell, types, infinite, cartesian-product

Several similar questions have been asked and answered. One can find instances, for example:

1. [Cartesian product of 2 lists in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119730/cartesian-product-of-2-lists-in-haskell)
2. [Cartesian product over a list of lists in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476077/cartesian-product-over-a-list-of-lists-in-haskell?rq=1)
3. [How can I compute a Cartesian product iteratively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419370/how-can-i-compute-a-cartesian-product-iteratively?rq=1)

However, neither of what I have found answered my question completely.

#### Question

In Haskell, is it possible and how to define a function `cartesianProduct` that takes **arbitrarily (finitely) many** lists **of different types** and outputs their cartesian product on the nose?

#### Background

For example, in the links above one can find a `cartesianProd_2` that intakes two list of different types elegantly:

```
cartesianProd_2 :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
cartesianProd_2 list_A list_B = [(x,y) | x<-list_A, y<-list_B]
```

One can easily generalizes this to `cartesianProd_n`, for some fixed integer n.

However, I hope I can define one that does

```
cartesianProd (list_1,list_2) == (cartesianProd_2 list_1 list_2)
cartesianProd (list_1,list_2,list_3) == (cartesianProd_3 list_1 list_2 list_3)

-- and so on .. notice that list_i is a list of elements of type i.
```

One *immediate obstacle* I encountered is that I don't even know what **type** of `cartesianProd` is! Its domain is a tuple of (lists of different types)! What should I do then?

### Edit

If it is not possible in Haskell, please include a (pointer to a) proof.

Comment: The second of your links seems to be exactly this - except it uses lists instead of tuples as the input type, which neatly avoids exactly the problem you've encountered. You can't use a tuple to represent a sequence with an unknown number of elements.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I don't quite get it.. doesn't the type `[[a]]` mean it's a list of list of elements of the **same type**?

Comment: oh yes, that's a good point, I somehow overlooked that tuples would allow you to use different types.

Comment: @amalloy suggests that this cannot be done! I would definitely like to see a proof for that statement for Haskell and even some higher theoretical languages.

Comment: It can be done if you know what types are used and accept you will have to wrap them in a new `data` for your output.

Comment: That's something what I'm avoiding.. :(

Answer (score 7):

*If you are curious how to manipulate type-level data structures to solve the problem as stated, read on.  If you have a practical problem to solve, skip all this nonsense and skip to the **In Reality** section.*

This can be done.  It takes a bit of type-level machinery to get us off the ground.  Ideally I would like the following signature:

```
cartesianProduct :: Tuple (Map [] ts) -> [Tuple ts]
```

Here `ts` is a type-level list of types, and `Map` is a type-level version of `map` on lists.  `Tuple` takes a list of types and gives a type which is equivalent to a tuple of those types.  Let's say `[Int, Char]` for example, then this signature would reduce to:

```
cartesianProduct :: Tuple [ [Int], [Char] ] -> [Tuple [Int, Char]]
          -- morally, at least, equivalent to
                 :: ([Int], [Char]) -> [(Int, Char)]
```

Which hopefully you can see matches our intention.  So let's get going:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators, GADTs #-}

type family Map f xs where
    Map f '[] = '[]
    Map f (x ': xs) = f x ': Map f xs

data Tuple ts where
    Nil :: Tuple '[]
    Cons :: t -> Tuple ts -> Tuple (t ': ts)
```

This is using a number of advanced features.  Type families, data kinds, and GADTs are the key words.

Ideally this should be enough:

```
cartesianProduct :: Tuple (Map [] ts) -> [Tuple ts]
cartesianProduct Nil = [Nil]
cartesianProduct (Cons xs xss) = [ Cons x ys | x <- xs, ys <- xss ]
```

Sadly, GHC can't figure it out

```
• Could not deduce: ts ~ (t0 : ts0)
  from the context: Map [] ts ~ (t : ts1)
```

It doesn't know that `Map` is injective<sup>1</sup> (even though it obviously is), so it can't figure out what `ts` should be when the input type is `Tuple (Map [] ts)` and the pattern is `Nil`.  The technique here is to use a *singleton*, which is a type that helps the typechecker out of these situations.

```
data ListS ts where
    NilS :: ListS '[]
    ConsS :: ListS (t ': ts)
```

Notice that for a given list of types `ts`, there is only one possible `ListS` that could inhabit `ListS ts` (thus "singleton").  If we add this singleton as a parameter to our function, then the typechecker knows that, if the pattern is `NilS` then `ts` must be `[]` (and similarly for cons):

```
cartesianProduct :: ListS ts -> Tuple (Map [] ts) -> [Tuple ts]
cartesianProduct NilS Nil = [Nil]
cartesianProduct (ConsS s) (Cons xs xss) = [ Cons x ys | x <- xs, ys <- xss ]
```

Which passes the typechecker.  Using it requires a bit of work:

```
example :: [Tuple '[Int, Char]]
example = cartesianProduct (ConsS (ConsS NilS)) (Cons [1,2] (Cons ['a','b'] Nil))

unTuple2 :: Tuple '[a,b] -> (a,b)
unTuple2 (Cons x (Cons y Nil)) = (x,y)

ghci> map unTuple2 example
[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b')]
```

It is a shame that we have to manually convert into a real tuple to see it working.  But deriving a `Show` instance for `Tuple` is going to be another big hassle.

### In Reality

However, the fact that we have to use `unTuple*` at the end of this madness, which knows precisely how many types we have, should be a hint that we should be able to do without, with a bit of a reframing of our problem.  And indeed there is such a reframing, and that is the good ol' list applicative.

```
ghci> (,) <$> [1,2] <*> ['a','b']
[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b')]
ghci> (,,) <$> [1,2] <*> ['a','b'] <*> [True, False]
[(1,'a',True),(1,'a',False),(1,'b',True),(1,'b',False),(2,'a',True) (2,'a',False),(2,'b',True),(2,'b',False)]
```

Applicative notation works on arbitrarily many lists, as long as you can simultaneously provide an n-ary function to combine the elements (here the tupling functions `(,)` and `(,,)` play that role, but it could be any function, e.g. `(\x y -> x + 2*y) <$> [1,2] <*> [3,4]`).  And in practice, this is almost certainly the way a problem requiring n-ary heterogenous cartesian products would be solved.  The type-level fanciness discussed in this answer is seldom required and often just makes things unnecessarily complicated.

---

<sup>1</sup>I attempted a new injectivity annotation to fix this

```
type family Map f xs = r | r -> xs where
    Map f '[] = '[]
    Map f (x ': xs) = f x ': Map f xs
```

But it was no help.  Seems like it should have worked.

Comment: Injectivity annotations are borderline useless in current GHC. What they do is allowing some types that would be regarded as ambiguous. What they do not is what everyone would expect, namely making `x ~ y` to be deduced from `F x ~ F y`, provided `F` has been annotated as injective. I have no idea why this is the case.

Comment: Thank you for such thorough answer.. I will need some time to digest.

Comment: @Student, feel free to ask any questions you have

Comment: And see also [`(<+*+>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.1.1/docs/Data-Universe-Helpers.html#v:-60--43--42--43--62-) for a drop-in replacement to `(<*>)` that handles infinite lists correctly.

Answer (score 5):

This cannot be done, for exactly the reason you end with: tuples of different sizes are unrelated types, and you cannot generalize over them. For the same reason, Haskell has no generic `zipWithN` for zipping together N lists of different types. You have to either accept a `[[a]]` as input (requiring all inputs to be the same type), or else specialize to particular tuple sizes (`cart2`, `cart3`, `cart4`, etc).

I suppose I should state for completeness that in principle I think you could rewrite this as a variadic function in the same way that `Text.Printf` works - instead of a tuple of size N, accept N separate arguments. But even then I'm not sure how you could get it to return input shaped like `(x, y, z)` instead of `(x, (y, z))`.

Comment: Oh no!! Does that suggest we need higher language? Or it's a proven fact that we cannot ever reach the "highest"? Sorry if this question is a bit vague.

Comment: Also, is there any proof for the fact that you suggested? If there is any argument, I'd love to hear! Even if it's for other general theoretical languages.

Comment: Also, if this is true (that there exists no such language), then things get very interesting. For mathematicians, taking the cartesian products of different types is easier than breathing. What makes the difference between theoretical languages and their imaginations?

Comment: I mean, of course it can be done in other languages with different type systems. It's fairly easy in Lisp or Python, for example. Clojure's type system doesn't distinguish between lists and tuples, and also doesn't insist on homogenous lists, so even if Clojure were statically typed you could implement this with a signature like `[[Object]] -> [[Object]]`.

Comment: Very sad.. is there a proof for that it's not possible to achieve this within haskell?

Comment: @Student, I disagree with the others; I believe this is possible, but it will take quite a bit of custom type-level machinery to even represent the type of this function. I am thinking something like `cartesianProd :: Tuple (Map [] ts) -> [Tuple ts]`. Lovely as this is, this kind of thing often ends up being kind of a pain. I will write up an answer later if I remember (feel free to remind if its been a while by @'ing me)

Comment: @luqui What package is that Tuple constructor from? I can't make much sense of it, and as you can imagine a search for "tuple" returns a lot of unrelated stuff.

Comment: @amalloy, I made it up, but it's `HList` (I wasn't 100% sure that's what HList meant).  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58927394/33796).