# Checking numbers while making list: "Can't match expected type 'Bool'"

Tags: haskell

So, I just recently started working around with Haskell and I'm trying to make something that makes a list, for example, from [1..99] and checks the numbers that are divisible by the sum of their digits, for example, 63 (6+3 = 9, 63 divides by 9).

I was doing the following:

```
digits = map digitToInt . show
inac = [x | x <- [1..99], digits x] -- (testing here)
```

It gave me the following error :

```
<interactive>:83:38: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘[Int]’
    • In the expression: digits x
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: digits x
      In the expression: [x | x <- [1 .. 999], digits x]
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is just a rookie error.

Comment: Your problem here is that map returns a list of Int, you need to instead sum your digits, then do an actual check. That check will return a Bool, which will satisfy your `digits` call

Comment: Try to add types, or at least ask your development environment about the types it infers for the functions. For examples, what's the type of `digitToInt`?

Comment: I see, the thing is, I want to check those which satisfy the condition and then in the end, display how many (from the list) meet the condition and then display which ones.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I tried adding types before, like this: `digs :: Integral x => x -> [x] `. And this: `digits :: Integer -> [Int]`.
None worked for me, giving the error : The type signature for 'digits' lacks an accompanying binding.

Comment: It's hard to follow along when you present what you've done as a narrative in the comments here. Please edit your question and show what you've tried.

Comment: To write both a type declaration and its definition in GHCi, you have to enter them both at once using multi-line input with the `:{` and `:}` commands. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8443096/402884

Answer (score 2):

This is the general form of a list comprehension:

`[ expr | pattern1 <- expr1, pattern2 <- expr2 ..., test1 ,test2 ... ]`

That is to say `test1`, `test2` etc are all `Bools`. These are boolean values that are tested to see what goes into the list.

Your expression has a problem:

```
[x | x <- [1..99], digits x]
--                 ^^^^^^^^ Here
```

The problem is, `digits x` isn't a `Bool`, it's an `[Int]`. The correct expression would be:

```
[ x | x <- [1..99], x `rem` sum (digits x) == 0]
```

In English, we would read this as "All numbers x from 1 to 99 where the digits of x divide x."

Your issue was, you were trying to say that a list of digits was a `Bool`, and GHC didn't understand.

Comment: I had tried something similar to what you wrote there using ``mod`` and it gave me some type of error I can't recall, I'll be trying out all of these tips from everyone and come back with feedback later on.

Comment: @Wireless Why didn't you mention that in the question? `div` is almost equivalent to `mod`, you can look at the docs later. Did it work?

Comment: I forgot, since I did lots of different attempts at making it work, still didn't test it out, currently waiting for my mom since she asked me for a favor, might be a while till I come back with feedback xD

Comment: `div` is used for integer division. I think you meant to use `rem` or `mod`.

Comment: Oh dear, you're right! What a mistake. I'll correct that immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking anything at the guard part of the list comprehension. You may do as follows;

```
digits :: Integral a => a -> [a]
digits 0 = []
digits n = digits (n `div` 10) ++ [n `rem` 10]

inac :: Integral a => [a]
inac = [x | x <- [1..99], x `rem` sum (digits x) == 0]]

*Main> inac
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,18,20,21,24,27,30,36,40,42,45,48,50,54,60,63,70,72,80,81,84,90]
```

Comment: Why does it give me this as soon as I type in the first line?:  `<interactive>:7:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: digits :: a1 -> [a1]`
Does it have something to do with the fact that I'm just using Prelude?

Comment: @Wireless In GHCi you need to declare it all at the same time. Use a file instead, or say `let (expression); (expression);` instead of one at a time.

Comment: @Wireless Make sure you have the `digits` function is defined. Have you copied all of the above to the file that you are loading to GHCI..?

Comment: I was simply using ghci Prelude, no file, maybe would have been easier with a file from the start, will try it out and come back with feedback later on, thanks :D

Comment: @Wireless Just store the above snipped in a file called `whatever.hs` in a directory and then go to that directory and run `stack repl`. When you see `Prelude>` prompt type `:load whatever.hs`. The prompt changes to `*Main>` . Then type `inac`.

Comment: @Redu tested out right now, working just fine, thanks for the help :D