# Why does this create a StackOverflow Error?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I've started using Haskell lately, and defined this seemingly simple function:

```
f 0 = 1
f x = x * f x - 1
```

However, it results in this:

```
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> f 0 = 1
Prelude> f x = x * f x - 1
Prelude> f 10
*** Exception: stack overflow
Prelude>
```

Comment: GHCi doesn't realize you are defining _one_ function `f`. It proceeds line by line so `f x = x * f x - 1` is a function `f` shadowing the previous definition of `f` (`f 0 = 1`). To enter a multiline block, enter `:{`. Close that block with `:}`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443035/multi-line-commands-in-ghci

Comment: You're function definition also defines `f x` using `f x`. Your definition means that `f x = x * (f x) - 1`, not `x * (f (x - 1))`

Comment: @Alec It didn't work: Prelude> :{
Prelude| f 0 = 1
Prelude| f x = x * f x - 1
Prelude| :}
Prelude> f 10
*** Exception: stack overflow
Prelude>

Comment: @MarkNeu Sure it didn't, but not for the same reason. Note that `x * f x - 1` gets parsed as `(x * f x) - 1`. Did you mean `x * f (x - 1)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your factorial seems innocent, but it isn't. It's parsed like this:

```
f 0 = 1
f x = x * (f x) - 1
```

What happens if we use `f 1`?

```
f 1 = 1 * (f 1) - 1 = 1 * (1 * (f 1) - 1) - 1
    = 1 * (1 * (1 * (f 1) - 1) - 1) - 1
    = 1 * (1 * (1 * (1 * (f 1) - 1) - 1) - 1) - 1
    = ...
```

I'm going to stop here. This will never end. It will build up a stack of parentheses, and at some the whole tower collapses and you end up with a stack overflow.

You have to use parentheses:

```
f 0 = 1
f x = x * f (x - 1)
```

Now we get the correct result:

```
f 1 = 1 * f (1 - 1) = 1 * f 0 = 1 * 1 = 1
```

Keep in mind that this works only in an implementation file. In GHCi you have to use multi-line mode or a semicolon:

```
ghci> f 0 = 1; f x = x * f (x - 1)
ghci> -- or
ghci> :{
ghci| f 0 = 0
ghci| f x = x * f (x - 1)
ghci| :}
```

Otherwise later definitions will shadow earlier ones. Note that your prompt might differ.