# Can I use == and /= without using Eq?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

So I wrote this program and everything works fine ;) 
I would like to improve it. I would also be able to compile two different time sets with the use of /= and get True as an result. 
I am a little bit confused.

```
data Time = Localtime {hour, minute :: Int}
              | Globaltime {hour, minute, difference :: Int}
              | LocaltimeAM {hour, minute :: Int, am :: Bool} 
             deriving Show

same :: Time -> Time -> Bool
same u1 u2 = (h u1) == (h u2)
   where
      h :: Time -> (Int, Int) -- (Int, Int) = (hour, minute)
      h (Localtime h m) = (h, m)
      h (Globaltime h m d) = ((h+d+24) `mod` 24, m) 
      h (LocaltimeAM h m am) = (h + (if am then 0 else 12), m)
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this works, since a `data`type needs to start with an **u**percase.

Comment: Furthermore it is not really clear to me what the problem is. What do you mean with "two different time sets with the use of `/=`? You can define a `different :: Time -> Time -> Bool`, or make it an instance of `Eq`.

Comment: I do not want to use Eq. Yes, I could define  "different", but my question is if it is possible to combine different and same in one function.

Comment: "combine different and same in one function" I don't understand what you mean by this. I assume that the result of `different a b` is different than the result of `same a b`, right? If so, then they must be two different functions.

Comment: @BroniaBerlin: yes, add an extra parameter that specifies if you want the "same" or "different" flavor. But the standard approach is to make `Time` an instance of `Eq`, such that one can *reuse* the `(==)` for all kinds of objects. Furthermore all of a sudden, you can use functions like `nub`, that have as condition that the elements they `num` are of an `Eq` type.

Comment: `h` looks like a canonicalization function; it essentially converts any `Time` to `Localtime` form, except it's a tuple. By the way, it is incomplete for reality; we do have odd timezones like +12:45.

Comment: I guess what you're looking for (for whatever reason) is something like 'named implementations' that Haskell doesn't have and Idris does http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#named-implementations

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To answer the question in the title:

> Can I use `==` and `/=` without using `Eq`?

You could - technically speaking - explicitly hide the `Eq` typeclass in the prelude, and then define a `(==)` and `(/=)` function yourself, but that would be a bad idea, since it would mean that you can no longer compare two integers with `(==)`.

What you probably want is to make `Time` an *instance* of the `Eq` typeclass, such that you can from now on write `time1 == time2`. We can make it an instance like:

```
h :: Time -> (Int, Int) -- (Int, Int) = (hour, minute)
h (Localtime h m) = (h, m)
h (Globaltime h m d) = ((h+d+24) `mod` 24, m) 
h (LocaltimeAM h m am) = (h + (if am then 0 else 12), m)

instance Eq Time where
    t1 == t2 = (h t1) == (h t2)
```

Haskell will automatically write the `(/=)` function for us (as the opposite of `(==)`), or you can decide to write the `(/=)` version, and then Haskell will write the `(==)` version. Of course you can also implement both.

Making types a member of a typeclass actually can be useful. Take for example the [**`nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) function. It requires that the type `a` is a member of the `Eq` typeclass, and performs some sort of "uniqness" filter: you provide it a list of elements, and it returns a list of *non-equal* elements. Now without any work to define a `nub` function for your `Time` type, by making `Time` an instance of the `Eq` type class, you can use `nub` on a list of `Time`s.

Of course you can not simply make a type an instance of all possible type classes. You should only make types an instance of the `Eq` typeclass if you can check if two items are the same (and there should thus be a "reasonable" idea when two items are equal). Furthermore most of these typeclasses come with "*contracts*": for example an equality relation (like defined by `(==)`) should be *reflexive*, *symmetric*, and *transitive*.

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful. Could you tell me how I would compile this in my ghci?

Comment: @BroniaBerlin: you can write it between `:{` and `:}` lines to implement a multi-line item: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443035/multi-line-commands-in-ghci

Comment: I've never used Eq before so I am kinda lost right now, so if I would like to compare two time sets I would write what exactly?

Comment: >Prelude : Time (Localtime 13 20) (Localtime 14 20) would be false with my previous function

Comment: @BroniaBerlin: and it is `False` if you write `Localtime 13 20 == Localtime 14 20`.

Comment: "how I would compile this in my ghci?"  GHCi is an interpreter and not capable of compilation.  I know this is not actually answering your question, which is addressed by Willem, but it is worth realizing when the question itself is misleading/unanswerable and why.

Comment: you make the best answer of this kind, I always enjoy reading your posts. Congrats. +1