# Command "ghc" returning Variable not in scope

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am starting in Haskell and encounter this weird error message when trying to compile a .ghci file in Haskell. I have this very simple code for example:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Greetings! What is your name?"
    inpStr <- getLine
    putStrLn $ "Welcome to Haskell, " ++ inpStr ++ "!"
```

I saved the code in a file called `basicio.hs` and tried to run
`ghc basicio.hs`
Instead of the String I get the following message

```
<interactive>:2:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: runghc :: t0 -> b0 -> c

<interactive>:2:8: error: Variable not in scope: basicio
```

I am not sure what's wrong, the command ":load" works fine and find my file.

Comment: How did you load the file? What flags did you use to run `ghci`?

Comment: Well ifor ghci I run it directly without addings any flags after `ghci` in the shell.
The command to compile that I have tried was simply `ghc basicio.hs`.

Comment: did you load the multiline statement between `:{` and `:}` ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443035/multi-line-commands-in-ghci

Comment: I did save the code to a file named `basicio.hs` and tried to compile the file. So I guess I don't need the `:{ :}'

Comment: what if you load it with `ghci basicio.hs`. I can not reproduce it if I write `:l basicio.hs` or `:load basicio.hs`.

Comment: The command `:load basicio.hs` works as expected without any error, although  `ghci basicio.hs` returns the same error as in my post. I don't seem to understand where does the problem comes from...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error messages looks like it was generated by typing "`runghc basicio`" at the GHCi prompt:

```
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from ...
> runghc basicio

<interactive>:3:1: error: Variable not in scope: runghc :: t0 -> t

<interactive>:3:8: error: Variable not in scope: basicio
>
```

However, the `runghc` command, and the compiler command `ghc` are both meant to be run directly from the command line.